# Moving Caravan Encounters

Tags: dnd-5e, combat, encounter-design, mounted-combat, vehicles

I have to set up a few encounters where my players are part of a small caravan, about 4 small wagons being pulled by horses and oxes.

I am needing some help on if there are any rules pertaining to combat in a moving vehicle such as cover, attack roles, certain save throws, and if there are any advantages and disadvantages while attack in/on a wagon as well as initiative order.

A follow up question is where to locate the rules with mounted combat while targeting a moving target to attack. I can't seem to find the rules in the "Dungeon Master's Guide" or I just haven't seen it yet.

Answer (score 4):

5e leaves much of the adjudication and rule-improvisation to the DM, which means the rulebook does not explicitly say what rule covers each specific scenario that comes up in a game. It falls heavily on the shoulders of the DM to improvise such rules as needed.

There is support for the above statement mentioned in the rulebooks; for instance:

> ### Advantage and Disadvantage
>
> ... The DM can also decide that circumstances influence a roll in one direction or the other and grant advantage or impose disadvantage as a result.
>
> (page 173 in the PHB)

It is within your power (and the heavy, heavy responsibility) as DM to rule these things out. For further reading, take a look at [The Angry GM’s Marvelous Mechanical Miscellany for Ad Hoc Adjudication and Improvisational Invention](http://theangrygm.com/marvelous-mechanical-miscellany/). **WARNING: SWEARING**. Scroll down to the "Modifiers" part, that's what you're looking for, but you might want to read the whole article.

Other things I have, personally, improvised rules for in similar situation:

**Concentration Saving Throws** for certain situations, as per the Concentration Rules in PHB 203:

> The DM might also decide that certain environmental phenomena, such as a wave crashing over you while you're on a storm-tossed ship, require you to succeed on a DC 10 Constitution Saving Throw to maintain concentration on a spell.

---

There are rules spelled out as you mention, the **Chase** rules can be found in DMG 252, they are pretty solid and I create my own chase complications table all the time.

The **Mounted Combat** rules can be found in PHB 198, they're pretty disappointing but I wouldn't modify this too much as the players have access to the same rules.

The **Cover** rules can be found in PHB 196. Cover grants bonuses to AC and Dex Saving Throws, which make PCs so much harder to hit, entrenched as they are. Tip: throw in some chase complications that flush them out of their cover.

Comment: Don't forget the Cover rules. Merchant wagons are full of stuff you care about less than your health.